# Changing arrows style in tikz-cd

Tags: arrows, tikz-styles

I am working with a lot of diagrams, and I like the font mathabx, at least for the arrows.
I managed to have \rightarrow in mathabx style, so when I am using that command (and related, like hook, left and so on) it is fine.
However, my diagrams are drawn with tikz-cd, and the style of the arrows does not correspond.
I know I can change the style of the arrow with stealth, but can I also change it so it will be like mathabx style?

As example, here the arrow I like:

[image]

Here a little diagram, just to test.
In general, I am putting many decorations on my arrows, like "thick", "two heads", "dotted" and so on.

```
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

%change style of arrows
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz, diagrams={>=stealth}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B\ar[dl] \\
    C & 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the style named `math font`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

%\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

%change style of arrows
\tikzcdset{arrow style=math font}

\begin{document}
$A\rightarrow B$

\begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B\ar[dl] \\
    C &
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It doesn't work for every font, because Ti*k*Z tries to guess the placement of the stem and it may not adjust well with every math font. However, `mathabx` aims to be compatible with standard Computer Modern fonts, so the heuristics work well in this case.

There's no need to load the `arrows` and `arrows.meta` libraries, because `tikz-cd` does it for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, it is a little blurry, at least in my output. As I was saying, I have quite some decoration for my arrows, in particular, I need some of them to be bold and it does not work properly.
But I can see that it is a little too much too have all, and your solution is working otherwise!

Comment: @BarbaraGiunti Blurry? Are you on MiKTeX?

Comment: Sorry, more shaky than blurry. Like the tail and the head are forced over a line which does not fit. And the bold arrow became just arrows with a thicker line in body.

Answer (score 1):

What about tweaking the tikz stealth arrow a little bit? Maybe you can play around with the correct values but after a quick try I came up with the following parameters. There is definitely still a difference but it is somehow similar to the mathabx arrow.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz, diagrams={>={Stealth[round,length=4pt,width=4.95pt,inset=2.75pt]}}}

\begin{document}
$A\rightarrow B$

\begin{tikzcd}
    A \ar[r]\ar[d] & B\ar[dl] \\
    C &
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]